# Is there a way to magic sign-in (clicking on customized URL) in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

For a portal, we are using Azure AD B2C for authenticating users. We want to bypass username, password entry for users by providing URL embedding username and password. When a user clicks the URL, the application should authenticate and load the application directly.
Using login_hint in AAD B2C URL, we can enter the username. But we do not see an option of entering the password or doing the sign in.
Is this possible with AAD B2C custom policies. If so how?

Comment: It's possible with a signed JWT that you provide to B2C. Though there you don't provide the password, you provide the claims the user should have. Don't consider putting password in the URL because it will get saved in browser history.

Comment: Here's a sample that uses this approach for invitations https://www.github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies%2Finvite%2FREADME.md

Comment: That’s the solution above. Server generates a magic link and displays it to the user. Link is generated by that sample.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been resolved by @junnas comment, post it as an answer to close the question.

> It's possible with a signed JWT that you provide to B2C. Here's a
> [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/README.md) that uses this approach for invitations.